Override syntax highlighting rules for Neovim colorscheme
I want to override highlighting for a language-specific keyword in Neovim.
I've figured I can do it via vim api (eg. vim.api.nvim_set_hl). This approach does work with elements like Comment or LineNr, but doesn't seem to work with rubyInstanceVariable.
:checkhealth says Ruby parser is installed:
Parser/Features        H L F I J
 - ruby                ✓ ✓ ✓ ✓ ✓

colors.lua
function ColorMyPencils(color)
    color =  color or "default-color-scheme"
    vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("ColorScheme", {
        pattern = "*",
        callback = function()
            -- This works
            vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, "Comment", { fg = "#818589" })
            vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, "LineNr", { fg = "#818589" })

            -- This doesn't work
            vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, "rubyInstanceVariable", { fg = "#818589" })
        end,
    })
    vim.cmd.colorscheme(color)
end


return {
    {
        require("zeropoop/my-color-scheme").setup({}),
        ColorMyPencils("my-color-scheme")
    }
}

I'm just starting with Vim and Lua and will appreciate any advice.

Looks like the problem was in Treesitter plugin, which uses it's own syntax highlighting rules.
